# Multi-threaded debugging in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: multithreading, intellij-idea

I am relatively new to IntelliJIdea. I am running version Ultimate 2019.2.

I am doing a multi-threaded debugging and it seems like IntelliJ suspends all threads once one of the breakpoints got hit. This means, at a given time I can work with one breakpoint only, I do not have the visibility into how my multi-threaded app is behaving. 
In Eclipse I would see all suspended threads and I could've worked with any breakpoint I wished in any of suspended threads.

How can I configure smth like that in IntelliJ?

I have seen that I can select a breakpoint and then select a behavior for it: stop all threads or stop only a thread on which it was invoked. That's nice.

But I do have several dozens of breakpoints and I do not want to go back and change that behavior for each breakpoint separately. Can I configure this behavior globally??

Pls, advise. This is super annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have figured it out: when changing suspension behavior for a given breakpoint, there is a button `Make Default` that allows setting this behavior for all new breakpoints created after the change. Breakpoints created before the change will have their behavior unchanged.